# Adwords API - find Product Group by Product ID

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

So I need a way to find a product group (aka product partition/AdGroupCriterion) by product (aka item, offer) id.

Doesn't really matter how, through one of the services or through reports.

So far I haven't been able to find any relation between a product group and a product. So any advise on how the two are related will be much appreciated.